# Microsoft C++ Native Test Fails Assert::AreSame even when values are the same

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm running a test with microsoft native unit testing framework (that comes with vs2019) and it fails with this message: `Assert failed. Expected:<1> Actual:<1>`

Here is the test code:

```cpp
TEST_METHOD(memory_copy)
{
    int ref[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int src[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int dest[10];

    test::memory_copy<int>(src, dest, 10);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Assert::AreSame(src[i], ref[i]);
        Assert::AreSame(dest[i], ref[i]);
    }
};
```

> Note: `memory_copy<>()` copies memory from one pointer to another, just like `std::memcpy()`

Does anyone have an idea what may be the issue here?

Comment: Show us the `test::memory_copy<T>` implementation, without this, there is not much we can do.

Comment: I've confirmed that test::memory_copy<T> works. I've also found the issue. Gonna post answer in the moment.

Comment: I believe `AreSame` checks memory addresses, not values. `AreEqual` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Assert::AreSame()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#general_are_same) checks whether the inputs refer to the same **object**; it does not compare the values.

The implementation of the function (from `CppUnitTestAssert.h`) is as follows:

```
template<typename T> static void AreSame(const T& expected, const T& actual, const wchar_t* message = NULL, const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)
{
    FailOnCondition(&expected == &actual, EQUALS_MESSAGE(expected, actual, message), pLineInfo);
}
```

What you can see here, is that it's comparing memory addresses, as opposed to the contents. [`Assert::AreEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#general_are_equal), on the other hand, compares the objects for equality.

```
template<typename T> static void AreEqual(const T& expected, const T& actual, const wchar_t* message = NULL, const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)
{
    FailOnCondition(expected == actual, EQUALS_MESSAGE(expected, actual, message), pLineInfo);
}
```

Comment: Is that really the full implementation for `AreSame`? This can be tricked by overloading `operator&`. It should be using `std::addressof` instead.

Comment: @walnut, yes it is. The `AreEqual` has several overloads, but `AreSame` just has the one. I was very surprised it doesn't use `addressof`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `Assert::AreSame()` doesn't do what I expected it to do. By changing it to `Assert::AreEqual()` I've solved the issue. More info here:

[Microsoft Documentation on AreEqual()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#general_are_equal)

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: This answer has been posted before the one I've already upvoted and selected as an answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I should have checked the timestamps.